# Is there a way one can send different emails to different people using nodemailer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, nodemailer

I want to send an email to the user saying

```
hey u have successfully registered please refer the code below 234234
```

and an email to the owner saying

```
user 234234 has registered
```

```js
            let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service: 'gmail',
                port: 587,
                secure: false,
                requireTLS: true,
                auth: {
                    user: MYEMAIL,
                    pass: MYPASSWORD,
                }
            })

            const randomGenerator = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000)
        
            let mailOptions = {
                to: [
                            { name: "Receiver Name 1", address: "receiver1@example.com" },
                            { name: "Receiver Name 2", address: "receiver2@example.com" },
                    ], 
                subject: 'You have successfully registered, Please refer the code given below',
                text: `Your code is ${randomGenerator}`
            }
        
            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
                if(err) console.log(err)
                else{
                    console.log('email sent' + info.response)
                }
            })
```

so far i've tried making an array of subject and text so that the email sends them orderwise, but instead, it sent the same email to the user and owner twice

Comment: To send different emails, use separate calls to `.sendMail()`.

Comment: Just call sendMail twice with different content... this almost seems too obvious, have we missed something?

Comment: @ADyson ohhh right that works, my bad!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `.sendMail()` more than once and feed it different addressees and different email content each time you call it.  One call to `.sendMail()` has one set of addressees and one piece of email content.  So, to send different content, use separate calls to `.sendMail()` and vary the inputs.

Comment: yes i got it, unable to post any answer for my own question right now due to low quality answers in the past